# list method here does not work. It would throw: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, typeerror

I saw it on [programiz](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/list) and [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_list.htm) that I can use `list()` to convert any iterables like strings or tuples to lists. In the first website, it gives the following example:

```
vowelString = 'aeiou'
print(list(vowelString))
```

and in the ipython shell it would give something like:

```
['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
```

However, when I tried to run the same code on my jupyter notebook, it returns:

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Does it have anything to do with the current version of my jupyter notebook? I am not quite sure why such an error would arise on my notebook....

This is the version I am now using:

> C:\Users\USER\Anaconda2\envs\py3k\python.exe
>
> 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: Have you defined `list` as a variable earlier in your code? Don't do this. Start a fresh session with these two lines and you will not see this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot replicate this result, the example you've given is perfectly valid. It may be the case that you've accidentally overwritten the default list builtin by doing something like

```
list = ...
```

which means the next time you try to call list you get the error. Check your code and if you have done this, restart the kernel.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.  If this is *correct*, then the question is a duplicate of many previous problems in reusing `list`.

Comment: Restarting the kernel worked for me. Thanks!